# List index out of range due to index error

Tags: python

Represent a polynomial $$p(x) = a0 +a*x+a2*x^2+⋯+an*x^n$$  as a list of coefficients $$[a0,a1,a2,…,an]$$ . Write a function called poly_eval which takes two input parameters p and c, where p is a Python list of numbers representing a polynomial  p(x)  and c is a number, and returns the value  p(c) .

```
def poly_eval(p,c) :  
    n = len(p)    
    poly_num = [p[i]*(c**i) for i in range(0,n+1)]  
    poly_sum = sum(poly_num)    
    return poly_sum


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-7aabb00c0ade> in <module>()
      1 "Check that poly_eval returns the correct values."
----> 2 assert poly_eval([1,1,1],1) == 3
      3 print("Problem 3 Test 1: Success!")

<ipython-input-17-dce9ef404880> in poly_eval(p, c)
      1 def poly_eval(p,c) :
      2     n = len(p)
----> 3     poly_num = [p[i]*(c**i) for i in range(0,n+1)]
      4     poly_sum = sum(poly_num)
      5     return poly_sum

<ipython-input-17-dce9ef404880> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 def poly_eval(p,c) :
      2     n = len(p)
----> 3     poly_num = [p[i]*(c**i) for i in range(0,n+1)]
      4     poly_sum = sum(poly_num)
      5     return poly_sum

    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm confident that my code is on the right track but I must be missing something. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please copy and paste your code instead of using an image. Also, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: From the flagging options - "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers_"

Answer (score 2):

```
 def poly_eval(p, c):
     n = len(p)
     poly_num = [p[i]*(c**i) for i in range(0, n)]
     return sum(poly_num)
```

You must iterate from (0, n) not (0, n+1), because if you do so, then you will be representing polynomial upto x^n+1 not x^n.
Since the list has only n elements, it will show index error if you would access n+1 th element.